# How to make SQLite preallocate memory during startup?

Tags: c, linux, sqlite, memory

I'm working on an embedded program that uses SQLite, and I want more predictable memory usage.

I read https://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html and wanted to use the "Zero-malloc memory allocator" described in section 3.1.4. If I understand it correctly, it tells SQLite to allocate a fixed amount of memory at startup, and use it exclusively, instead of making dynamic allocations (malloc) at runtime.

On my Ubuntu desktop (so nothing to do with embedded), I compiled the latest SQLite with -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMSYS5, created an example program which tells SQLite to preallocate 1GB RAM and then sleep for 15 seconds. I wrote a test script to check 'free' before and after running the example.

Unfortunately, I don't see the preallocation reflected in the 'free' output. What gives? My example checks every SQLite return code and I didn't get any errors. How can I make SQLite reserve the memory immediately during startup?

My test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o verbose
free -b
./testsqlite3 &
sleep 3
ps aux | grep testsqlite3
free -b
```

Output:

```
$ ./runtest.sh 

free -b
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     8421400576   607322112  6244298752    28102656  1569779712  7066603520
Swap:             0           0           0

./testsqlite3 &
sleep 3
Using libsqlite version 3.40.0, sqlite3.h is version 3.40.0
Preallocating using MEMSYS5
Opened database successfully
Table created successfully
Sleeping for 15 secs before exiting. Call 'free -b' now.

echo "bash sleep complete, confirming app still running"
bash sleep complete, confirming app still running
ps aux | grep testsqlite3
user1     7474  0.0  0.0 979960  2380 pts/1    S+   12:11   0:00 ./testsqlite3
user1     7477  0.0  0.0   5116   880 pts/1    S+   12:11   0:00 grep testsqlite3

free -b
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     8421400576   607420416  6244200448    28102656  1569779712  7066505216
Swap:             0           0           0
```

My example program testsqlite3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;

    fprintf(stdout, "Using libsqlite version %s, sqlite3.h is version %s\n", sqlite3_libversion(), SQLITE_VERSION);


    fprintf(stdout, "Preallocating using MEMSYS5\n");
    //int preallocateMemoryBytes = 100000000; //100MB
    int preallocateMemoryBytes =   1000000000; //1GB

    rc = sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP,
                        malloc(preallocateMemoryBytes),
                        preallocateMemoryBytes, 32);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to config SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    rc = sqlite3_initialize();
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "initialize() failed\n");
        return(-1);
    }


    //open DB
    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

    if( rc ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(-1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }


    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COMPANY("  \
          "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
          "NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
          "AGE            INT     NOT NULL," \
          "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
          "SALARY         REAL );";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        return(-1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
    }


    fprintf(stdout, "Sleeping for 15 secs before exiting. Call 'free -b' now.\n");
    usleep(15000 * 1000);

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Linux doesn't allocate real memory until you actually use it. Until then, the memory sits in a limbo state of "memory the program could use so far it hasn't"

Comment: Is there some other command I could run that would let me observe this limbo memory? I want to see some number decreasing by 1GB.

I really want to be sure that the 1GB I wanted to preallocate will be used by libsqlite3 and nothing else. Not even other components of my process.